# Replacing a character in a string

Tags: java, string

I am replacing a character in a string. There has to be a better way to do this, right?

```
public static String eqEq(String stringIn) {


    char[] stringArray;

    stringArray = stringIn.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringIn.length(); i++){

        if(stringArray[i] == '='){

            stringArray[i] = '?';
        }

        }

    String sReturn = new String(stringArray);
    return sReturn;
}
```

Comment: Check out `StringBuilder`.

Comment: [`stringIn.replaceAll("=", "?");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: String.replace/replaceAll?

Comment: Just curious, but would they allow `String.replace()` in a job interview?

Comment: @pcnThird - Why not?  The purpose is to get the job done, not to jump through hoops.

Comment: @pcnThird Why not?  It demonstrates and understanding of the API

Comment: @pcnThird reminds me of the story about the physicist who had to calculate the height of a tower depending on some given values - he simply asked the concierge as the board of professors didn't specify anything in particular and after all the profs where asking what he is doing he came up with >8 other solutions he could have calculated the height. There are multiple ways of achieving your goals - as long as you can explain your intend and fall back to other strategies, why not?

Comment: I didn't even know about this! Thank too all that helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something wrong with `replace()`?

```
public static String eqEq(String stringIn) {
    return stringIn.replace('=', '?');
}
```

Note that `replace()` replaces *all* occurrences, but uses plain text search/replacements, unlike `replaceAll()` which is the regex version of `replace()`.

Also note the `replace()` has two versions: One version that has `char` parameters (used here), and another that has `String` parameters in case you want to search/replace more than one character.

Comment: @MadProgrammer `replace()` has two versions: [one for chars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), [another for Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence) (well CharSequences actually). I suppose in this case we should use the char version. Done.

Comment: Sorry my bad :P Keep forgetting about the `CharSequence` one

Answer (score 2):

You could try [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29), for example

```
stringIn = stringIn.replace('=', '?');
```

You could even use [`String#repalceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) if you want to use a regular expression instead.

You could even use a `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);
int index = -1;
while ((index = sb.indexOf("=")) != -1) {
    sb.replace(index, index + 1, "?");
}
```

The choice is yours

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods on the String class, as follows:

```
public static String eqEq(String stringIn) {
  stringIn.replace("=", "?");
}
```

OR

```
public static String eqEq(String stringIn) {
  stringIn.replaceAll("=", "?");
}
```

See a [live example](http://ideone.com/bT9EXP) of this code running (using `replaceAll`) on a sample string.